# How to run Web interface for Graylog?

Tags: docker, graylog

I have run graylog-docker. I have tried the

- GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  and
- GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://localhost:9000/
  In this case I can run the Web Interface in a browser on the local machine "mypc" the same where docker is running.
  When I run http://mypc:9000 from another machine in the LAN I see an empty page"
  How to fix it? to have access to the Graylog in docker from other machine in the LAN?

Comment: Can you try with `GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://0.0.0.0:9000/` ?

Comment: It  does not work even from the local computer. If I set  GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://mypc:9000/ then it works from other machine. But it  is connected with machine name. If I pass it to other user he must edit the docker-compose file